# Style a property in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I got React noob question.. The thing is that I have a method with a mount of JSX attributies with their respective properties. 
The question is, how can I get to the imageUrl attribute a style? such as give border-radius: 10px or centering in the page.

```
xxxx (item:aaaa, index:bbb) {
        return (
            <div className="Post ms-u sm3 ms-u-lg3 ms-u-xl">
                <div className="content">
                            <PersonaControl
                            id={"BlogItem" + index}
                            identifier={item.blogOwnerEMail}
                            displayName={item.blogOwnerName}
                            size={PersonaSize.extraLarge}
                            hidePersonaDetails={true}
                            imageUrl={item.blogLeaderPicture && item.blogLeaderPicture}
                            labels={this.props.labels}
                            />
```

Here is the render method. I try to double the information of the property xxxx how calls me the content of the parameter aaaa:

```
 render() {
   return (
    <div className="clearBoth"></div>
    <div className="bandContent" style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }}>
     {this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems.map(i => {return this.leadershipBlogDataItems(i, this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems.indexOf(i))})}
     <div className="blogPost"></div>
```

Comment: Please, provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code. With it, would be easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What the `imageURL`? a `bool` prop of the `<Person/>`?

Comment: export interface IPersonaControlProps {
    id: string; // Used for identification of HTML elements
    identifier: string; Account name ("username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com") 
    displayName?: string;
    imageUrl?: string;
    size: PersonaSize; // For Persona Control (not the Callout)
    hidePersonaDetails: boolean; // For Persona Control (not the Callout)
    controlSecondaryText?: string;
    controlTertiaryText?: string; // For Persona Control (not the Callout)
    calloutDirectionalHint?: DirectionalHint; // For Persona Callout
    className?: string;
    labels: ROP.LABELS;

Comment: export default class PersonaControl extends React.Component<IPersonaControlProps, IPersonaControlState> { constructor(props: IPersonaControlProps) { 
        super(props);
        const imageUrl: string = props.imageUrl != null && props.imageUrl !== "" ? props.imageUrl : null;
        this.state = { dataLoaded: false,
            personaData: {
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                calloutImageUrl: imageUrl, }};}

Comment: render() { try { return ( <Persona
                        size={this.props.size}
                        imageInitials={ROP.Helper.getInitials(this.state.personaData.displayName)}
                        primaryText={this.state.personaData.displayName}
                        secondaryText={this.props.controlSecondaryText}
                        tertiaryText={this.props.controlTertiaryText}
                        hidePersonaDetails={this.props.hidePersonaDetails}
                        imageShouldFadeIn={true}
                        imageUrl={this.state.personaData.imageUrl}/>

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to add a style property. You can do this by adding:

```
<div style={{ border: "1px" }} > </div>
```

If you want to add the "classic" css, with a file, simply add a className to the div, and import the css file as shown below.

```
import "./style.css";

<div className="yourstylename"> </div>
```

Inside style.css you simply add your css. By the way, the import shown above only works if the css file is in the same folder as your component/js file.